# x2go aborts while starting

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, x2go

I am connecting to a server xfce with the `x2go` Client, I am on Mac OSX, the session is aborted with:

```
Error: Aborting session with 'Unable to open display 'nx/nx,options=/tmp/.x2go-user/C-user-173-1610379165_stDXFCE_dp32/options:173''.
Session: Aborting session at 'Mon Jan 11 16:33:18 2021'.
Session: Session aborted at 'Mon Jan 11 16:33:18 2021'.
Loop: WARNING! Signals were not blocked in process with pid '30901'.
Warning: Signals were not blocked in process with pid '30901'.
```

I was connecting just 3 days ago. I don't think I have changed anything since then.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The problem was with my local XQuartz installation

Comment: Which problem and how it was solved? Without just more extended information this answer is going to be deleted.

Comment: I do not know. I just reinstalled XQuartz and it was fine